# Unpublished data exchange

Tags: data

While doing anthropological fieldwork I shared some films on a hard disk with an international research scholar in the same field it also had my unpublished data and chapters in progress. While her research objectives are different there are overlapping areas of interest. She borrowed films but we did not get a chance to have any mutual exchange. I did not mind this but later I realised she was having fun at my expense. Now I am scared I compromised my data and chapters. Since they are very personal and open to interpretation I am still hoping it is safe.

Comment: There isn't a question here.

Comment: Question is can she use my unpublished data/ chapters in her work which is focussed in the same domain but addressing different research questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say if you have legal copies of those films, but since you effectively gave her the contents of your drive you gave her your data...

> "I am still hoping it is safe"?

Safe from what? could she use the material - not sure, this may be a legal issue - how would she reference it? Would this be plagiarism as you effectively gave her your data.

> I did not mind this but later I realised she was having fun at my expense

Perhaps you should contact her and ask her to delete that material...
Good luck.

Comment: Unlikely for her as a scholar to have transferred my data files especially as she herself pointed out that she uses a macbook pro and I am on windows. Can she substantiate claims with reading the unpublished work I doubt, but yes I feel I compromised on the ethics of data use.

Comment: I use my macbook pro to repair / read drives from pc and mac... In fact the mac seems to get to pc drives and sort them better (in my experience) than a pc. So, any data was available to her imho...